# Unable to deque messages from Topic after the listener listens the messages in spring jms

Tags: java, spring, jms, jmstemplate

I am sending the messages to Topic using `oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory`. The messages are stored in DB topic . Using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` , the messages are being listen .But the problem is the messages are not dequeueing or deleting from the topic i.e., the messages are stucked in topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know they're stuck in the topic? Do you get the same message delivered to your listener multiple times, or do you mean it's still in the database?

Remember, messages on a Topic are supposed to be delivered to multiple consumers, so it shouldn't be too much of a surprise if the message is still hanging around after being delivered to your listener - it might think there are other clients still to be delivered to.

Comment: I mean it is still in the database. But once the message is listened,I don't want that message to be in data base.It should be removed.